# PHP - login script

Tags: php, authentication

I have this login script, but for some reason its not working. I checked the database, the form, and I have re-written the script in like 5 different ways; however, they all have the same problem, it does not start the session. Here is the code:

```
<?php 
session_start();

//connect and select DB
mysql_connect ("localhost", "root", "") or die ('Error: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('usr_info')or die ("cannot select DB :(");

//transfer values sent from form
$usrname = $_POST['usrname'];
$passwrd = $_POST['passwrd'];

//injection protection
$usrname = stripslashes($usrname);
$passwrd = stripslashes($passwrd);
$usrname = mysql_real_escape_string($usrname);
$passwrd = mysql_real_escape_string($passwrd);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM usrs
        WHERE usremail='$usrname'
        and passwrd='".md5($_POST['passwrd'])."'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

//count the number of rows found with the given info
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);

//the matched result must be equal to 1
if ($count == 1) {
    $_SESSION['u_name'] = $usrname;
    header("Location: ../../landing.php");
    exit();
}
else {
    echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
```

this is the form im using:

```
<div id="login-signup" class="letters2"><a href="javascript:blankfunction()">Login | Signup</a></div>
<div id="point-1" class="point-1"><img src="site-wide/point-1.png" width="405" height="131" />
  <div id="login-form">
  <form id="login" method="POST" action="site-wide/effects/login.php">
    <label for="username"></label>
    <input type="text" name="usrname" id="usrname" value="email" onfocus="clearMe(this);" onblur="unClearMe(this);"/>
    <label for="passwrd"></label>
    <input type="password" name="passwrd" id="passwrd" value="password" onfocus="clearMe(this);" onblur="unClearMe(this);"/>
    <input type="image" src="site-wide/submit.png" name="submit" id="submit" value="login"/>
  </form>
```

this is the usrs table in my db:

usrs

```
Field    Type          Null  Default  Comments  
ID           int(4)        No  
usrfname     varchar(15)   No    
usrlname     varchar(15)   No        
usremail     varchar(45)   No   
passwrd      varchar(8)    No  
usrage       int(3)        No 
usrgender    varchar(7)    No
```

I found the answer xD .. the problem was the database. the password field only had 8 characters whereas the actuall md5 password had over 15. so all i did was increase the number of characters the field can handle and viola!

Comment: just realized that it actually skips over the whole 'if' statement.

Comment: I told you there is no good in this code, lol :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Works fine on my end, just adding what jogesh_p suggested.

Please check if the session has been started prior to continue with the rest of the script. May it be throwing any error? Set the error_reporting like that:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
if (!session_start()) {
    die("The session hasn't been started!");
}
```

This way you can check if there's any error before proceeding.

Comment: just checked it, the session does start

Comment: but it skips the if statement. did I type the sql query correctly?

Comment: Have you tried to do a little debugging? Like `var_dump($count);` or checking if mysql_query is returning any error (maybe something like `mysql_query($sql) or print(mysql_error());` could help as well).

Answer (score 0):

i think you also have to check that the username and password is submitted or not??

with

```
if(isset($_POST['submit_button_name'])){
   // then your code
   // and if the both are submitted and
   // match into the database then use session_start();
}
```

Comment: I just added 'echo $count;' at the end of the script. and '$count' returns 0 everytime

Comment: @user1095145 it means that the user from you are trying to login not exits in your database..

Comment: @user1095145 check further things : 1. First try to echo $_POST[], to ensure the inputs, 2. check the datatype of password fields with length, or the password that stored in database is in md5 format or not, or also post your data structure with some users..

Comment: just echoed $_post[]. it is passing the input values. the password in the db is stored in md5.

this is the usrs table in my db:

usrs

    Field  Type     Null  Default  Comments <br/>  
    ID          int(4)     No  
    usrfname  varchar    (15)   No    
    usrlname  varchar    (15)   No      
    usremail  varchar    (45)   No   
    passwrd  varchar    (8)           No  
    usrage  int(3)      No 
    usrgender  varchar    (7)           No

Answer (score 0):

if $count is 0 then most likely you are entering wrong credentials.
But just give this a try. change the query to

```
SELECT * FROM usrs
    WHERE usrs.usremail = '$usrname'
    and usrs.passwrd = '".md5($passwrd)."'
```

Comment: Probably not `usrs.usremail = '$usrname'`  but `usrs.usremail = '{$usrname}'`

Answer (score 0):

I had written a php login script and shared an article on it... here are the codes:

```html
<?php
include 'inc/config.php';
$err = "Enter Your Email and Password";

$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'email',FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
$password = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'pwd',FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

if(isset($email) && isset($password)){ //If Email and Password is Given then Continue
 $q = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'");
 if(mysqli_num_rows($q)>0){ //Checking Email from the Database
     $password = sha512($password);
   $u = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email' AND pwd='$password'");
   if(mysqli_num_rows($u)>0){ //Matching Email and Password from the Database

    //Download the script to get the full code

       $_SESSION['username'] = $data['username'];
       $err = NULL;
       $time = time()+(24*60*60); //Setting time for 24 hours
       setcookie("mct_session",true,$time); //Setting Cookie
   }else{
       $err = "Email and Password doesn't match";
   }
 }else{
  $err = "No User Account Found";
 }
}
if(isset($err)){
    header("Location: index.php?err=".$err); //Login Failed
}else{
    header("Location: dashboard.php"); //Login Success
}
?>
```

and the form i was using is:

```html
      <form class="login-form" action="login.php" method="POST">
         <div class="form-group">
           <label form="email">Email:</label>
           <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" class=form-control required/>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
           <label form="pwd">Password:</label>
           <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="pwd" class=form-control required/>
         </div>
         <div class="form-action">
            <div class="col-sm-12"><a href="#" onclick="toggleForm()" class="pull-left font-bree font-2x">Sign Up</a><input type="submit" class="submit_btn btn pull-right" value="Login"/></div>
         </div>
      </form>
<!--Login Form Ends-->
```

Check it out http://mycodingtricks.com/php/php-login-script-with-example/

Answer (score 0):

This login is vulnerable to SQL injection, consider using PDO.

Answer (score -1):

You should probably use the same password variable name here:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM usrs WHERE usremail='$usrname' and    passwrd='".md5($_POST['passwrd'])."'";
```

To:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM usrs WHERE usremail='$usrname' and passwrd='".md5($passwrd)."'";
```

Do you get redirected? Or does it say wrong user/pass?  If you are redirected, then it seems that the credentials are passed and the user is authenticated.  Did you check the session?

Comment: Also please consider using PDO otherwise your scripts are open to SQL injection.

Comment: Any comments would help.  What happens after this script is run and you attempt to log in?  Do you see any errors? Is it just the session? Whats the problem specifically?

Comment: after running the script it just gives me the error message 'wrong user name/ pass' it never redirects

Comment: That means the query didnt return a row. Make sure your query is correct and that you have the user stored in the database.  Is the sql field name usremail = $usrname correct?

Comment: could be any number of things at this point.  You are going to have to debug.  One obvious thing is that the stored password must be md5 hashed.  Other than that check your values and make sure they are what you expect them to be.

Comment: Not `usremail='$usrname'`  but `usremail='{$usrname}'`